# how to delete the second occurrence of string in paragraph

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a Paragraph like this

> I saw Susie sitting in a shoe shine shop. Where she sits she shines,
>   and where she shines she sits.

So that i want to delete the string which occur more than one time. In the above Paragraph she, sits, where, shines repeats more than one times. I want to delete the strings need output like this.

> I saw Susie sitting in a shoe shine shop. Where she sits shines, and.

Did anyone guide me to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

Without allowing for punctuation, you could try something in these lines:

```
s1 = "I saw Susie sitting in a shoe shine shop. " _
   & "Where she sits she shines, and where she shines she sits."
a1 = Split(s1, " ")

For i = 0 To UBound(a1)
    For j = i + 1 To UBound(a1)
        If a1(j) = a1(i) Then
            a1(j) = ""
        End If
    Next

Next

s2 = Trim(Join(a1, " "))
```

Comment: The below like code too works fine. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/isvvba/thread/2ce86f3b-08ce-47e5-bd89-60ec21160083?prof=required

Comment: @HarvestHappiness Your tags say `access-vba`, but the link above is for MS Word VBA. Please ensure you use valid tags when posting questions.